# What does this clause explain: the subject or the preceding object?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I am trying to shorten the following sentence:

> When the mirror is rotating at a large angle, the mirror reflects the light away from the lenses.

into:

> The mirror diverges the light from the lenses when rotating at large angle.

Does the new sentence have the same meaning ? My concern is: does the clause *'rotating'* explain the mirror or would it inadvertently refer to the lenses ?

Comment: The second sentence is fine, except for the use of *diverge*: it isn't transitive, and its meaning is quite different from *reflect*. (When talking about optics, it usually means what a divergent lens does.) You probably want "The mirror reflects the light away from the lenses when rotating at large angle."

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I check the dictionary for diverge, it has two forms: intransitive and transitive, the latter is synonymous to deflect. So diverge is ok.

Comment: Transitive *diverge* is so rare that most native speakers won't recognize it. If you mean *deflect*, that's a better word, but *reflect away* is even better.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your second example is confusing from the exact cause you suspected.

You can do it this way:

> When the mirror is rotating at a large angle, it reflects the light
>   away from the lenses.

or

> The mirror rotating at large angle diverges the light from the lenses.